# table() with rows all zeros

Tags: r

This seems simple enough but I could not find an easy answer anywhere.

If we have the following data and use `table()`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","a"),y=c("b","a","c"))

table(df)
   y
x   a b c
  a 0 1 1
  b 1 0 0
```

whats the easiest way to get:

```
   y
x   a b c
  a 0 1 1
  b 1 0 0
  C 0 0 0
```

without adding the `c` row manually after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way. Essentially, you need to make sure that `x` and `y` both have the same levels. I do that by computing the `union()` of their respective `levels()` and then `transform()` the original `x` and `y` to both have this common set of levels:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","a"),y=c("b","a","c"))
> lev <- with(df, sort(union(levels(x), levels(y))))
> lev
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> df <- transform(df, x = factor(x, levels = lev), y = factor(y, levels = lev))
> table(df)
   y
x   a b c
  a 0 1 1
  b 1 0 0
  c 0 0 0
```

Your example has an easy solution - just give `x` the same levels as `y`, as the levels of `y` are complete. In more general situations where neither `x` nor `y` has a complete set of levels, the code I show will get that complete set for you and thus works in both situations.

Comment: +1 Great answer, thank you. union is actually new to me so i'll have a look at that in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it is:

```
levels(df$x) <- levels(df$y) <- union(levels(df$x), levels(df$y))
```

Generically or

```
levels(df$x) <- levels(df$y)
```

For your specific situation.

Then call table(df). Basically, you need to specify what "levels" are *possible* for your table.